# jQuery filter toggler function to show/hide images

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a "filter toggler" with jQuery, to use for showing/hiding images on a page that has different categories applied to them (using a rel attribute). The filter is outside the list of images, so I need to address them by comparison (I think?) of values.

I can't seem to find a way of applying the "On" switch for fading out all images that are not of the current category. See code below:

```
$('#filter a').toggle(function() {
    // On
    $('.nodes a').removeClass('inactive');
    $('.nodes a').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    $('.nodes a').animate({opacity: 1}, 1);
    $('filter a').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 1);
    $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1);
    var filter = $(this).attr('rel');
    $('.nodes span').not('.' + filter).parent().addClass('inactive');
    $('.nodes a.inactive').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 250);
    $('#filter a').not(this).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 250);
}, function() {
    // Off (Reset)
    $('.nodes a').removeClass('inactive');
    $('.nodes a').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    $('#filter a').animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
});
```

The HTML structure is as this -

```
<ul class="nodes">
 <li>
  <a>
   <span>
    <img>
   </span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
<div id="filter">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#" rel="category">Category</a>
  </li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

Edit: Found a solution, see updated code. Could probably use more tweaking but it will do for now.

Comment: I'm guessing you could gain by doing `var $nodesspan = $('.nodes span'); $nodesspan.etc...`. (AKA, jQuery caching to prevent excessive DOM searching.)

Comment: You should add that to your question content, not add it as a comment. `:)`

Comment: Thanks :) I'd try and avoid any caching or other methods, there aren't really that many categories for the script to run through (client has asked to be able to add new categories but it will most likely stay in the 10s).

Comment: Typo spotted on 6th line of 1st code block - missing # in selector.

Comment: I would really advise you to read about DOM query caching and method chaining. Here, for instance, caching $('.nodes a') would really speed things up.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Lapple, yes I rewrote the script and I've made sure to chain as much as possible and caching the DOM references in variables. Helped more than I thought it would.